# Multi Insert within same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

It might be a retarded question but even after 2 hours of searching I just cant find any good way to deal with that..

I am trying to switch 2 rows within one table...

i broke the structure down to that:

```
ID time 
 3  100
 5  200
```

the rows do have more columns in the actual code but i only need to swap those two values..

I tried to achieve this with two Update statements .. But in the end i ended up with 4 sql statements and connections therefore :/ .. I had to change every value in a single sql to make 100% sure they swap the right way. But it seem pretty bad code

If i swap the values with 2 update sqls the second one fails because there is no unique matche in the table anymore ...

I googled for hours to find a way to achieve this with one sql and one connection but i failed.

so at the moment i am doing:

---

```
$query = "UPDATE `" . $table . "` SET...; 
$db->insert($query);

$query2 = "UPDATE `" . $table . "` SET...;
$db->insert($query2);

... two more times
```

Comment: Is ID an auto-incrementing primary key? If so, you may want to question your design approach as to why you would be changing these values.  That seems to be a very odd use case.

Answer (score 1):

E.g.

```
UPDATE my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON x.id IN(3,5)
   AND y.id IN(3,5) 
   AND x.id <> y.id 
   SET x.time = y.time;
```

Comment: This swaps the time of around - thats correct - but the id´s need to swap as well. I tried to go for an extra line of     SET x.id = y.id; But that´s not working ..

Comment: @PhilLA Rows have no order in RDBMS, so the request makes no sense. The solution to that problem would simply be "ORDER BY id DESC" !!!

Comment: id is not AI .. as well id is not a randome number so id need to be swaped over as well. so the other values of that changed row will again fit to the right "event"...

Comment: @PhilLA You're not making a whole lot of sense. If id isn't PRIMARY, what is? And consider providing a more properly representative data set and (corresponding) result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use a placeholder ID value (I am using 99999 in this example). This reduces code to 3 simple sql statements.

```
update table set ID = 99999 where id = 3;
update table set ID = 3 where ID = 5;
update table set ID = 5 where ID = 99999;
```

Comment: Given that most autoincrement columns are signed, but only ever use the _positive_ part of the range, you can safely use the **negative** value for this.